# Finding roots of this polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I try to compute the roots of
$$p_4 = x^4 - 4 x^ 3 + 8 x^2 - 8 x + 4$$

Now Wolfram Alpha tells me this expression is the same as $$p_4=((x - 2) x + 2)^2$$

How do I see this? Is there any way to obtain this?

Edit: I know it is $p_4=(x^2 - 2 x + 2)^2$, but I would never obtain this by myself. I'm interested in knowing a way to see this without "guessing".

Comment: @dxiv how do I see that there are no real roots?

Comment: The first derivative $p_4^{\,'}(x)$ has easy-to-find roots. P.S. Took down my previous comment since it wasn't too helpful in this case.

Comment: @dxiv Ok thank you, I don't understand. When is it the case that the roots of the derivatives are roots for the polynomial?

Comment: `When is it the case that the roots of the derivatives are roots for the polynomial?` A common root of a polynomial and its derivative is a root of multiplicity at least 2 of the polynomial. But that's not what I meant. The roots of the derivative give the local extrema of the function. In this case, the only real root of $p_4^{'}$ is $x=1$ which turns out to be a minimum for $p_4\,$. But $p_4(1) \gt 0\,$, therefore $p_4 \gt 0$ for all real $x\,$, in other words $p_4$ has no real roots.

Comment: @dxiv I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Factor out $x^2$ in the first three terms:
\begin{align}
x^4-4x^3+8x^2-8x+4&=x^2(x^2-4x+4)+4x^2-8x+4\\
&=\bigl(x(x-2)\bigr)^2+4x(x-2)+4\\
&=\bigl(x(x-2)+2\bigr)^2.
\end{align}

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! Really nice!